# Finding duplicates in a column B using column A?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this (sorry for the terrible looking table)

```
bnavn   | emnekode | grnr      
------------------------------
moetd   | inf1300  | gruppe10
moetd   | inf2220  | gruppe10       
amirf   | inf1300  | gruppe7    
amirf   | inf2220  | gruppe7    
hannams | inf1300  | gruppe1    
ninacma | inf2220  | gruppe3
```

I need to

A: Return the bnavn where emnekode is inf1300 & inf 2220 (which was easy)

B: Return the bnavn where grnr for inf1300 & inf2220 are duplicates.

I'm having trouble doing part B - I've tried JOIN and WHERE EXISTS, but nothing seems to be working correctly.

My code so far is:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT bnavn
 FROM emnestud
 WHERE emnekode IN ('inf1300', 'inf2220')
```

I'm having a lot of trouble setting up the next part, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: you'd need to use a `group by` clause and some `count()` functions to total up how many `gruppe` values there are in each group, then a `having` clause to filter out only the ones where count > 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT bnavn
 FROM emnestud
 WHERE emnekode IN ('inf1300', 'inf2220')
group by bnavn
having count(1)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

This code return the rows that are repeated for emnekode

```
SELECT emnekode
 FROM emnestud
GROUP BY emnekode
HAVING
 COUNT(*) > 1
```

this is helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT bnavn 
FROM emnestud 
WHERE grnr in(
  SELECT grnr
   FROM emnestud
    WHERE emnekode IN ('inf1300', 'inf2220')
    GROUP BY grnr
    HAVING COUNT(1)>1);
```

[`SQLFIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d135a/1)